# CakePHP HABTM queries

Tags: cakephp

What's the CakePHP way to do such queries?

```
SELECT news.* FROM news, users 
INNER JOIN news_users nu ON nu.user_id = users.id 
WHERE users.id = $user_id
```

I have a link table `news_users`, so trying with something like `$news = $this->News->findByUserId($this->User->id);` does not work, because it looks for `news.user_id`

P.S. The above query works, I just desire to make the script shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare **findByUserId** function in your **News** model:

```
//put this code in your News model
public function findByUserId($user_id = null)
{
    return $this->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'NewsUser.user_id' => $user_id
        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'news_users',
                'alias' => 'NewsUser',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'NewsUser.news_id = News.id'
                )
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

Then you can use your findByUserId function enywhere in your **NewsController**

```
//this code in NewsController
$news = $this->News->findByUserId($this->User->id);
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to be easier :| isn't is possible with `finderQuery` in the model somehow?

Comment: @RápliAndrás, probably even if you can it won't be easier solution. I changed my answer to make it simplier to use in controller.